# I want to start another activity when it is clicked?

Tags: android, android-activity

Well I have an activity which contains nothing but a relative layout with brown background,
and I want to start another activity if the users clicks anywhere on the screen, how would i do that ??

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainscreen);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, give ID to your `RelativeLayout` by putting `android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"` in your layout file then.

```
RelativeLayout l = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
l.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
       // startActivity here

    }
});
```

or without using your `RelativeLayout` just implement the `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` of activity

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        // start activity
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Note: Not yet tried this code.

Answer (score 1):

Add onClick attribute to your layout xml, and implement onClick method in your activity to start a new activity.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/myLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:onClick="onClick"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

In your activity add an onClick method.

```
public void OnClick(View v) {
  startActivity(new Intent(this,MyNewActivity.class));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your Mainscreen has Parent layout either Linear,Relative,Frame. Take reference of that and handle click listener.

Ex:
   If your Parent layout is Linear.

```
LinearLayout linear=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);

 linear.setOnClickListener(this);
```